# Style image called from ajax dynamically in css

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, image

I have an image file located in a database, populated as a div. Is it possible to style the image itself and not the div?

Reason why it is a div is because I am using Ajax to make a call and display logos based on what user selected in drop down menu.

Here is my jQuery code defining my image as a div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#employee").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var dataString = "empid=" + id;
    $.ajax({
      url: "submitlogos.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function (empData) {
        if (empData) {
          $("#errorMassage").addClass("hidden").text("");
          $("#recordListing").removeClass("hidden");
          $("#empId").text(empData.id);
          $("#empName").text(empData.name);
          $("#empFileName").html('<img src="' + empData.filename + '" />');
        } else {
          $("#recordListing").addClass("hidden");
          $("#errorMassage").removeClass("hidden").text("No record found!");
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```

The #empFileName variable is my image file in it's original img state.  That image was extracted from my database. In there, i have a column named 'filename' that stores all my images.

```
 <div id="empFileName"></div>
```

and here is my image disguised as a div!

Is it possible to style the image itself? I can style the div no problem but the image isn't effected. And I'd like to be able to style the image itself if possible.

Maybe there is an adjustment I can make to my Ajax even that may help?

Been at this all night trying to get around this using all the styling techniques I can think of SO FAR, but haven't been able to punch through yet.

Comment: Can be done by adding class to ajax returned image and adding style to it.

Comment: interesting. I figured it out, was very simple in CSS. Just added img after the id tag:

#empFileName img{
css code
}